# Where can I find the OFFICIAL Java Coding/Style Standards?

Tags: java, coding-style, standards, checkstyle

I use CheckStyle plugin for Eclipse and it does a wonderful job. I would like to know if there an official Code/Style standard (and there should be!) out there by Sun/Oracle... The ones I am finding are so out-dated, they don't even include any Java 1.6 specific syntax, etc...

Here is what I found so far:

http://developers.sun.com/sunstudio/products/archive/whitepapers/java-style.pdf (last modified 2000)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html  (last modified 1999 - [CheckStyle website](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net) references this)

I understand that to a degree most of the Java syntax has not changed much but you'd think it wouldn't be over 10 years old!!! Any ideas where to find an updated version or if there is any that I am just not finding?

Thanks

Comment: That is it. This has not changed much.

Comment: You can also see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334204/official-java-code-guidelines-conventions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try looking at the `-Xlint` compiler flag for `javac` for a programmatic check (if that's your question). It checks most things for you.

Also, what's wrong with having a code style document that's > 10 years old? That means the language is fairly stable and older code looks much like newer code, making maintenance easier. The library may have expanded but much of the syntax is identical. Your second link is what my searches returned and seems very comprehensive.

EDIT: If you want the nitty gritty details on the new Java syntax, check out the [Java Specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).

Comment: Thanks. I do understand that the syntax hasn't changed much as I stated in my original question but I was hoping that it would touch on NEW Syntax, example templating with <>, the for (x in y) syntax, annotations, etc.... all of which are not 10+ years old :)

Comment: i think we may be talking about new syntax then, not coding standards. The standards are things like having the curly brace on the same line as the declaration or not vs. syntax which is the ordering of characters that produces correct input for the compiler.

Comment: Agreed, but I did want both. I tried to hint at that with my title "Coding/Style"... by style, I really meant Syntax but perhaps that was confusing. Apologies.

Comment: Perfect, that will help actually. I am trying to get a set of programmers here to adhere to some sort of standards as everyone seems to follow their own :). Will accept your answer, thanks!

Comment: Have fun with that.  The problem with many of the style "standards" is that they are simply guidelines of which many are very subjective.  There are many which are adopted by most, none by all.  Debates on { at eol or newline soon to follow  ;-)

Answer (score 7):

To the best of my knowledge the internal Sun coding stds document was never officially updated to include conventions to encompass language changes such as Generics, Annotations, or now (in JDK 8) Lambdas etc.

I personally have always used the empirical style derived from the JDK itself, i.e if my code doesn't look like JDK code, then I am not following the coding practice.

Answer (score 3):

The links above are broken now since Oracle reorganized their web site.

http://web.archive.org/web/20090911103851/http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConvTOC.doc.html