# Java constructor overloading

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey

```
public class Drop_ABCD {
  private int First_number;
  private int Second_number;
  //Have one constructor overloaded with only one int 

  public Drop_ABCD(int First_number){
    this.First_number = First_number;
  }

  //Both getters & Setters set for First_number & Second_number
}
```

In the main class

```
Drop_ABCD abcd_obj = new Drop_ABCD(25485929);
ABCD_Main abcd_xml_drop = new ABCD_Main("drop",abcd_obj);
```

But when the XML is generated it as taken both `First_number` with `2548592` and `Second_number` with `0`,

Whenever the data type overloaded is 'int' , it populates all the other values of int types are set to `0`.

I don't want `Second_number` to be included at all, but it is included with a default value `0`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Don't you _ever_ want it included, or just not when it's set to 0, or just not when the constructor didn't include it or...?

Comment: I think you need to provide more complete code to explain what is going on.  You need [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't want Second_number to be included when the constructor is just to include only First_number

Comment: Side note: only deviate from standards if necessary. Like: don't use _ in java names. Java programmers don' expect to find _s in java code; so one will waste precious brain cpu cycles on ignoring them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Work on your conventions. [Where can I find the OFFICIAL Java Coding/Style Standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093596/where-can-i-find-the-official-java-coding-style-standards)
2. Familiarize the language semantics for primitives in java. 
   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html
3. Change the primitives to the object wrapper (int to Integer) and check on the difference.

Comment: This answer looks of no use to my problem statement

Comment: Your problem was that the the value of the second field is set to 0 which is the default value for primitive int.

Comment: My problem is that, I don't want that value to appear at all , Could you suggest how I can over come the same

Comment: Did you try the point number 3 - instead of using primitive use an Object which will be null if not initialized. Depending on how your mapper is configured it will not show up if it is null. (private Integer secondNumber).

Comment: Good. I would suggest you to change the problem statement, it has nothing to do with constructor overloading as you assumed.