# Single line blocks - are they considered to be bad style?

Tags: java, code-formatting

I'm fairly new to Java, and I'm unfamiliar with the general attitude towards one line blocks. For multi-line blocks, I use this style:

```
statement
{
    /*
     * code
     */
}
```

rather than

```
statement {
    /*
     * code
     */
}
```

because I absolutely hate the look of the latter. However, the former does take up more space. Therefore, for blocks containing one simple statement, I use one line to make my code more concise. Here's an example of how I generally write getters:

```
private int foo;
private int bar;
private int baz;

// Getters:
public int getFoo() {return foo;}
public int getBar() {return bar;}
public int getBaz() {return baz;}
```

Is this frowned upon? If not, what about something like this?

```
public <S, T> void printTwoArrays(S[] first, T[] second)
{
    for (S elem: first) {System.out.print("" + elem + " ");}
    System.out.println();
    for (T elem: second) {System.out.print("" + elem + " ");}
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter one way or the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all a matter of taste.  You will find that every programmer has his/her own style, but that in order to work with others without anybody being killed you have to settle on a common style.   Plenty exist.  I personally found that the default one used by the code formatter in the IDE used on a given project is "good enough" for most purposes, and that the benefit from at any given time being able to reformat the sources with a single command trumps almost all other arguments.  Also some IDE's like for instance IntelliJ actually presents the source differently than it is stored on disk so the point is essentially irrelevant then.

That said, I would suggest you write a *lot* of code and see what works best for you.  I tend to not put the brackets on separate lines, but instead use blank lines inside the source to group code logically.  Again, it is just a matter of taste.

See [Where can I find the OFFICIAL Java Coding/Style Standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093596/where-can-i-find-the-official-java-coding-style-standards) which most likely indicate what most *other* programmers would do.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on code conventions accepted within the project. If you is the only developer who is working on the project it is your call about to choose code style you use. However, in most java code I worked with or wrote myself I've rarely seen/used the code style you are using.
More likely, the code in your example would looked like this:

```
public <S, T> void printTwoArrays(S[] first, T[] second) {
  for (S elem: first) {
    System.out.print("" + elem + " ");
  }
  System.out.println();
  for (T elem: second) {
    System.out.print("" + elem + " ");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

As a side node - if I made code review for the code you provided in the example I would extract method for printing array into separate method. So instead it would looked even like this:

```
public <S, T> void printTwoArrays(S[] first, T[] second) {
   printOneArray(first);
   printOneArray(second);
} 

public <T> void printOneArray(T[] arrayToPrint) {
   for (S elem: arrayToPrint) {
     System.out.print("" + elem + " ");
   }
}
```

If you are interested in code conventions that more often use for writing java code I would also suggest you to google "java code style/conventions" and see what companies like Oracle or Google suggest for that.

Comment: The `printTwoArrays` method was just meant to show a one-line block between two statements, not as an example of code I actually use. And I skimmed through the code conventions from Oracle ([link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)) and couldn't find an answer to my question. It might've been there, but if so, I missed it.

Comment: (For Java 8+) If you really wanted to start extracting printing methods it would be much better to use a StringJoiner which avoids the loop and can be put inside the System.out.print statement.   See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html#StringJoiner-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-